# Is is possible to mimic drive by wire on a 1998 Jeep Cherokee using servos and other motors

Tags: power-steering, cherokee, self-driving

I have access to a 1998 Cherokee that is being used as a test bed for various learning projects.  It's only intended to be driven in a test area .. I believe it will not pass state inspection as is.

Anyhow, I am wondering if I can mimic drive-by-wire functionality and how difficult it would be, by potentially connecting a servo to the steering column, and a motor to the brake line/rod, in addition of course to a micro-controller that accepts the commands from Laptop/SoC.

Is this possible or am I being naive about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crew of the series Mythbusters did just as you've described, replacing the steering wheel with a geared servo motor controlled by radio control, along with throttle management. The brake pedal was also handled by geared servos. The need for this was to be able to destroy the rear axle of a vehicle without endangering a human operator.

A quick google search for "mythbusters remote control car" returns many results, all of which appear to have useful information. Too many to quote or link a single entry.

It's possible you'll discover other tinkerers who have completed the same or similar projects.