# Need Help Designing A Servo Mount To Turn The Steering Wheel on a Nissan Rogue

Tags: power-steering, steering-wheel, can-bus, active-lane-assist

I have a 2014 Nissan Rogue with a broken CVT, so rather than trade it in, I want to use it a test bed for some autonomous driving software.

It has a good steering angle sensor, and I already captured its values from CAN messages using a Raspberry Pi with a CAN shield and dbc file format:

```
BO_ 2 STEER_ANGLE_SENSOR: 5 XXX 
SG_ STEER_ANGLE_RATE : 16|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX 
SG_ SET_ME_X07 : 24|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX 
SG_ STEER_ANGLE : 0|16@1- (-0.1,0) [0|65535] "" XXX 
SG_ COUNTER : 32|4@1+ (1,0) [0|15] "" XXX
```

I manually turned the wheel and read the values and they seem sensible.
I then looked at ProPilot Assist, which has Lane Keep Assist (LKA), but the EPS control module that I would need to retrofit is $1500 used.

I sent some emails to junk yards around the country looking for it, but mostly they only sell the steering column and don't sell any of the ECU's, probably because they cant test them, not sure.

I haven't been able to find it on eBay yet either.

I remembered that Mythbusters did this "remote controlled real car" episode and some others on YouTube have done similar things.

Therefore I am looking for some help / guidance on building a simple mount with a servo that I can attach to the steering wheel to apply steering corrections, similar to how LKA works.

Although this is a test vehicle and not my daily drive, safety is an important requirement.  I need to be able to disable this system quickly and reliably and regain manual control.

Here's what I have found on YouTube, none of which look good:

1. universal control module that's way over kill: he built a full RC car with a Corvette.  Cool but not what I am looking for.
2. Direct Drive Steering Wheels For Video Gamers.
3. Some kind of metal wire through the gaps in the steering wheel and connected to the servo.

I am a software engineer with some car mechanics skills; mostly recently learned.  So drawing up a design and having it 3D printed is out of scope for me.

Before going to Fiverr, I thought maybe someone here has an idea or similar design, or had done something similar they would like to share?

Comment: This is a design question not relevant for this stack.

Comment: Perhaps a gear mounted to the shaft and a worm drive that can be cammed out of the way, but mounting needs to be strong enough to exceed all steering forces under any conditions. So not a maintenance or repair question.

Comment: This answer may also be useful: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/74962/10976

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is related to activities that are potentially dangerous. Remote controlling a car is cool (although probably off topic), provided it's done in a safe environment, a homemade system to test autonomous driving in live traffic is a literal accident waiting to happen.